# override NSScrollView "page scroll" behaviour

Tags: nsscrollview

I'd like to implement a custom "page scroll" behaviour for `NSScrollView`, i.e., what should happen when the scroll "rail" is clicked outside the scroll knob.

How do I detect that this event happened? I already have an `NSScrollView` subclass, and I would rather not subclass `NSScroller`.

I can override the `-scrollClipView:ToPoint:` method and determine if the scroll point is "far away" from the current scrollpoint, but this doesn't seem reliable.

Comment: Just an idea: replace the target and action of the scroller.

Comment: I tried. The action is also sent when the scroll knob is dragged, so I can't differentiate a click on scroll rail from another event.

Comment: Check the scroller's `hitPart` property.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. I just check if `hitPart` equals `NSScrollerIncrementPage` or `NSScrollerDecrementPage`. If you post this, I will validate this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSScroller` uses the target-action mechanism to tell the `NSScrollView` to scroll. The "page scroll" action can be intercepted by replacing the target and action of the scroller. The `hitPart` property of the scroller indicates how to scroll. Example in a subclass of `NSScrollView`:

```objectivec
@interface MyScrollView ()

@property id scrollerTarget;
@property SEL scrollerAction;

@end


@implementation MyScrollView

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    NSScroller *verticalScroller = self.verticalScroller;
    self.scrollerTarget = verticalScroller.target;
    self.scrollerAction = verticalScroller.action;
    verticalScroller.target = self;
    verticalScroller.action = @selector(myScrollerAction:);
}

- (void)myScrollerAction:(NSScroller *)sender {
    switch (sender.hitPart) {
        case NSScrollerDecrementPage:
            NSLog(@"Page Up");
            break;
        case NSScrollerIncrementPage:
            NSLog(@"Page Down");
            break;
        default:
            [sender sendAction:self.scrollerAction to:self.scrollerTarget];
            break;
    }
}

@end
```